# WebSocket connection to failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1

Tags: node.js, websocket, cpanel

A few months ago I have decided to build a collaborative drawing app to learn about node.JS.
I am hosting my website on O2switch with Cpanel but I have a recurring error after trying to draw some lines I can't draw anymore and the error in the console is :
WebSocket connection to failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1.

I don’t understand this error and would be happy to have some help.

here is the link to my website: http://draw.florianne.fr/

here is my Github with my code: https://github.com/florianne1212/real_time_collaborative_drawing_app

Thank you very much for your help.